# How to receive and process message from AWS SNS for normal .NET Console Application?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I tried a couple of ways and try searching online for the whole day but nothing works so far.

I found the AWS SDK sample but it is for AWS SQS not SNS: [Link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/ConsoleSamples/AmazonSQS_Sample/AmazonSQS_Sample/Program.cs)

What I want to do is similar to the sample but using a .NET Console Application to:

1. Publish a message to Topic A
2. Receive the message from Topic A and print it on the console

I found the AWS Guide has this [code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-example-code-endpoint-java-servlet.html) but it is in Java and I know nothing about Java.

Can anyone please help on how to do this? I really lost. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that this is a response to an old question... but I stumbled on this in my search and figured it's worth answering for the next person who does the same.

SNS in itself is a **push** mechanism, meaning it needs to actively seek out the target and push the notification to it. It does not hold onto a message you publish to it - if there are no subscribers, the published message is lost.
In order to do publish the message(s), the target (in your case, a .NET console app) needs to be listening, in some way, for the push. That also means that the target needs to be publicly available to the internet, which most .NET console applications aren't... unless you set them up to listen.

There are 2 main options here (obviously there's a thousand ways to shave a yak). I'll give my recommendation

**Recommended approach**

Create an SQS queue to subscribe to the SNS topic, then consume the message from that Queue.

The benefit of this approach is it's pretty easy to set up, and you're passing the "listening" responsibility onto AWS. Messages published while your consumer is down will not be lost, as SQS will hold onto them. In this way, SNS & SQS synergise quite well together: SNS receives the payload and "fans out" to subscribers, and SQS subscribes to that SNS topic and holds the message until it is consumed.

**Other approach**

You *can* set up your console app as a HTTP listener (or similar), and make sure it's listening on a port that is publicly accessible. This isn't likely to be the best idea for most use cases, as you need to open your firewall and likely isn't any better than just having an SQS queue look after this for you.

However, there are plenty of libraries such as Nancy that can turn your console app into a HTTP listener (effectively turning it into a HTTP REST API), and then you just configure an endpoint that SNS can subscribe to.

*Note: I've intentionally avoided putting links to examples, as it appears the resolution to this particular question is about educating on how SNS works... There's ample documentation easily accessible for either approach*

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/sns-apis-intro.html) are some examples to work with AWS SNS with .NET. AWS provides a lot of examples around AWS usage. You can start from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The examples seems to be publish to SNS. The one that I'm looking for is receive message from SNS topic...

Comment: [Subscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=SNS/MSNSSubscribeStringStringString.html) to a SNS Topic and you would be automatically getting the message.